# According to Pentecostals can a born again believer have spirits?

Tags: pneumatology, pentecostalism, demon-possession

According to Pentecostals, using Scriptural backing, is it possible for a born-again, Bible-believing, water-baptized, tongue-speaking, disciple of Jesus Christ have, or come under, or invite in an unclean spirit?

And a follow up question can he have clean spirits other than the Holy Spirit, multiple spirits including the Holy Spirit?

Comment: Again the tag demon-possession is merely added for search value but it’s a poor translation of the Greek δαιμονισθεις which would better be translated as demonized for those who care to answer the question. If you can prove demon-possession with Scripture from the original language I would welcome your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat 12v28 "But if I cast out demons by the Spirit of God, surely the kingdom of God has come upon you". E.S.V.

From this Scripture and surrounding verses it appears that when the kingdom of God comes upon someone that the Holy Spirit is not going to want to share His abode with any form of resistance to Himself. However, 2 points:

Jesus Himself e.g. at His temptations the devil "took Him" [Mat 4v8] up on a mountain and "said to Him". We are not told that the Devil entered Jesus but that the Devil appears to have some, no doubt temporary God given, influence on Jesus. Jesus heard what the Devil was saying, the Devil's words entered Jesus' mind in that Jesus reacts to them in His replies.
     From this we may understand, I think, as a Pentecostalist, that the Devil can attack, oppress and put his thoughts into our minds. But that is not taking up residence it is just putting something horrid through the letter box.

Secondly, when someone is a child of the Devil and is then reborn as a Christian initially they are not used to the new system. For all of us it takes time to see just how deeply false teaching e.g.[Mat 16:12] "the doctrine of the Pharisees" has entered our thinking.

Comment: What do you do with this passage? “And he said to her, "Let the children be fed first, for it is not right to take the **children's bread** and throw it to the dogs."”
‭‭Mark‬ ‭7:27‬ clearly the woman was asking for deliverance and Jesus says the bread is from the children (of faith) and not for the dogs (unbelievers). The idea that the Holy Spirit will not reside with another spirit seems very far fetched in that many examples exist where God has in his immediate presence unclean spirits, Job’s account the Accuser and vision told to Ahab of divine council with the lying spirit

Comment: Two more examples “you are to deliver this man to Satan for the destruction of the flesh, so that his spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭5:5‬ ‭Clearly a believer that would be saved but handed over to satan and also Paul himself “So to keep me from becoming conceited because of the surpassing greatness of the revelations, a thorn was given me in the flesh, a messenger of Satan to harass me, to keep me from becoming conceited.”
‭‭2 Corinthians‬ ‭12:7‬ ‭He says it was IN his flesh not ON his flesh. That’s inside the body.

Comment: Here is another example “And his master was angry, and delivered him to the tormentors  until he should pay all that was due to him. “So My heavenly Father also will do to you if each of you, from his heart, does not forgive his brother his trespasses.””
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭18:34-35‬ ‭the tormentors are the unclean spirits and in any case are you saying that a Christian can choose not to forgive and have no repercussions? That God will not have him over to the tormentors until he does forgive just because he is a Christian? Is Jesus not speaking to Peter and telling a future Apostle this?

Comment: @Autodidact When a murderer comes before a judge there is "immediate Presence" but no joint "residence". Paul's thorn in the flesh has been seen by some as poor eye-sight, hence "in the flesh". "Delivered to tormentors", Jesus was delivered to tormentors but remained perfect.

Comment: Jesus was not delivered on the grounds that he did not forgive. If the judge and the prosecution/accuser are in the same building but in different rooms they still reside in the same residence and certainly a judge will be in the same chamber with the accuser. You are assuming what the thorn was when the Bible makes it clear that at a minimum it was a messenger/angel of satan. You can’t reinterpret what is written. Jesus was talking to Peter and said if Peter would not forgive he Peter would be handed over to the tormentors too. I did give you a +1 for the Pentecostal view you shared.